# HttpListener (.NET Core) doesn't work with https on windows dockers

Tags: windows, docker, .net-core

.Net Core version: 3.1
OS: Windows 10 (1903)
Docker version: 19.03.5

Hi

I'm doing my first proof of concept on dockers and .Net Core in order to research possibility to move all of our infrastructure into dockers with .Net Core. I was trying to build a simple http listener that would return a hello world page.
I've found issue 
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3072
very helpful.

In short I'm trying to open two http listeners:
http://+:1234
https://+:12345

For this to work there are two URL ACL reservations on the host OS:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:1234/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Reserved URL            : https://+:12345/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

Also there is valid Certificate applied to the https port :

### SSL Certificate bindings:

```
IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:12345
Certificate Hash             : a05077849c0835b0db2b16656cd42651122f283d
Application ID               : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

...

Further both ports are forwarded to the container:

docker run --user ContainerAdministrator -p 1234:1234 -p 12345:12345 --name=https_container https_server_image

And container is running under ContainerAdministrator.

The HttpListener is working pretty fine on the http port.
For example trying to load "http://localhost:1234/" works fine (sample code just returns "Hello word" html page).
Trying to access SSL connection on "https://localhost:12345/" fails in the browser with "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Chrome/Edge, "PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR" in Mozilla.

Interesting part is that both HttpListener instances start without problem in the container and there is no any exception.
Of course the same test application works like a charm when started directly on the host machine without a docker containerization.

So I wonder do I miss something here ?
Is this intended behavior ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the "official" answer in the .NET Core [forum](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32721):

"In general the HttpListener class is a legacy component we ported from .NET Framework (which is Windows only) to .NET Core. But HTTPS functionality is not supported on Linux. See: #19752

If you need a cross-platform HTTP/HTTPS server, we recommend you use ASP.NET Core. The 'Kestrel' component supports HTTPS fully and is available cross platform (Windows/Linux/Mac).
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1"